# Autosize a ListBox that is within a GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I use a TableLayoutPanel that contains two GroupBoxes (the Layout has 2 columns). Inside these GroupBoxes I have, among other things, two ListBoxes (one for each GroupBox).

When I try to resize my form, the GroupBoxes succeed to adjust to the new size, but the ListBoxes don't. I've tried to change some parameters like the dock, the anchor, minimum size, modifiers, etc, based on others posts about more or less similar problems. But nothing seems to make my ListBoxes' size dynamic.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: It is easier to make your own user control. Put groupbox listbox etc... there. Then put your new user control in tablelayoutpanel. Easier to manage.

Comment: Make sure that the ListBox controls are children of the GroupBox control, and then set their Anchor properties. You'll probably want to anchor them on all sides to the parent GroupBox.

Comment: You can achieve desired layout simply by setting `Dock` and `Anchor` properties. For example set `Dock` property of `GroupBox` to `Fill` and then set `Anchor` of its child `ListBox` to `Top, Left, Bottom, Right`. Also set `IntegralHeight` property of `ListBox` to `false`.

Comment: To test if they really are nested, move the groupbbox. if the listboxes move with it then anchoring should work. Don't use dock.fill unless only omne control is in the gbox. For best advice we need to see the exact layout!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the answers and comments. I've found the solution!!
Actually the problem was a layout inside the groupbox; it was splitted in three rows, and the "syze type" of the row containing the listbox was setted to autosize. I just changed it to Absolute (in pixels) and that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

If you set all your controls to `DockStyle.Fill` and `AutoSize = true` you should be able to resize your listboxes.

If you have multiple controls in your groupboxes, I suggest you to use a `TableLayoutPanel` in it for every controls you want to be autosizing.

Also, you can set the `RowStyle` and `ColumnStyle` to `SizeType.AutoSize`.

In the form, this code works fine for me.

```
    private void InitComponents()
    {
        tableLayoutPanel1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
        groupBox1 = new GroupBox();
        groupBox2 = new GroupBox();
        listBox1 = new ListBox();
        listBox2 = new ListBox();

        tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
        tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize, 50F));
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(groupBox2, 1, 0);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(groupBox1, 0, 0);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));

        groupBox1.AutoSize = true;
        groupBox1.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        groupBox1.Controls.Add(listBox1);
        groupBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        groupBox2.AutoSize = true;
        groupBox2.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        groupBox2.Controls.Add(listBox2);
        groupBox2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        listBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        listBox1.AutoSize = true;

        listBox2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        listBox2.AutoSize = true;

        Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't knew listbox.AutoSize was acceptable!! It's not in the parameters' list...